# Generating a POT file

Tags: python, gettext, poedit, po, xgettext

PoEdit causes problems because it scans also the Python sources in subdirectories where no scan is desired. So I want PoEdit to get new information about strings from a POT file. [Here](http://www.poedit.net/trac/ticket/359) it is said that `xgettext` enables me to create a POT file from the sources. But I can't figure out how. It always generates a PO file.

How do I create a POT file with `xgettext`? Or is the old `pygettext` acceptable? Or is there another tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `xgettext` and rename the resulting `domainname.po` file to `domainname.pot`.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Template.html#Template

Answer (score 2):

Get [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/). It does just about everything you need pertaining to i18n and l10n you would need in a python project.

See also [instructions for setting it up in a Setuptools/Distribute project](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/0.9/setup.html); if you are not yet using them, I suggest you do